# How to add a new include file to NDK environment?

Tags: android-ndk

I want to build a android library with NDK, and my code used a new include file . 
The include file was added in kernel at kernel version 3.1.0. But my NDK environment doesn't contain the include file(NDK include path:NDK/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/linux), so when I compiled my source code, I get the error message is "error: linux/nfc.h: No such file or directory".

I don't know how to add a new include file for NDK environment. and the NDK include file is said "
***   This header was automatically generated from a Linux kernel header**
   of the same name, to make information necessary for userspace to
   **call into the kernel available to libc.  It contains only constants,**
   structures, and macros generated from the original header, and thus,
**   contains no copyrightable information.
".

Could I compiled a new NDK environment based my linux kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing the same thing a while ago. Though i cannot test it now, i will try to recollect and help you. By default in my build i did not have have libnfc.so(After boot up you can see logcat. It gives error messages related to libnfc).I did it on Samsung galaxy nexus S.. Then i had to manually copy the library(ofcourse first built it using NDK) and the corresponding header files. I think only 2 or 3 header files are there. You should do this tweeking. It might take some time but it should be easily done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry, I take so busy with other projects are not logged here. I tried it, but failed. So I think that compiled a HAL module  will be better than a library, but HAL module also need to call the kernel header files, and i don't know how HAL module linked and used by my kernel. there is a example for the the gralloc module:<pre>    #if HAVE_ANDROID_OS
    #include <linux/fb.h>
    #endif<code>I don't know HAL module how to used kernel header files.